# Python: plotting a combination of observations taken in the same day

Tags: pandas, matrix, plot

I have the following dataset:

```
id test date
1  A    2000-01-01
1  B    2000-01-01
1  C    2000-01-08

2  A    2000-01-01
2  A    2000-01-01
2  B    2000-01-08

3  A    2000-01-01
3  C    2000-01-01
3  B    2000-01-08

4  A    2000-01-01
4  B    2000-01-01
4  C    2000-01-01

5  A    2000-01-01
5  B    2000-01-01
5  C    2000-01-01
```

I would love to create a matrix figure with the count of how many individuals got a test taken on the same day.

For example:

[image]

Since we can see that 1 time (for one individual, id=1) test A and B were taken on the day; also for one individual (id = 3) test A and B were taken on the same day; and for two individuals (id=4 and 5) the three tests were taken on the same day.

So far I am doing the following:

```
df_tests = df.groupby(['id', 'date']).value_counts().reset_index(name='count')

df_tests_unique = df_tests[df_tests_re.duplicated(subset=['id','date'], keep=False)]

df_tests_unique = df_tests_unique[["id", "date", "test"]]
```

So the only thing left is to count the number of times the different tests ocur within the same date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the fun exercise :) Given below is a possible solution. I created a numpy array and plotted it using `seaborn`. Note that it's quite hardcoded for the case where there is only A, B, C but I'm sure you will be able to generalize that. Also, the default color scheme of `seaborn` brings opposite colors than what you intended but that's easily fixable as well. Hope I helped!
This is the resulting plot from the script:
[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5],
    'test': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
    'date': ['2000-01-01', '2000-01-01', '2000-01-08', '2000-01-01', '2000-01-01', '2000-01-08', '2000-01-01', '2000-01-01', '2000-01-08', '2000-01-01', '2000-01-01', '2000-01-01', '2000-01-01', '2000-01-01', '2000-01-01']
})
df_tests = df.groupby(['id', 'date']).value_counts().reset_index(name='count')
df_test_with_patterns = (df_tests[df_tests.duplicated(subset=['id', 'date'], keep=False)]
                         .groupby(['id', 'date'])
                         .agg({'test': 'sum'})
                         .reset_index().groupby('test').count().reset_index()
                         .assign(pattern=lambda df: df.test.apply(lambda tst: [1 if x in tst else 0 for x in ['A', 'B', 'C']]))
                         )
pattern_mat = np.vstack(df_test_with_patterns.pattern.values.tolist())
ax = sns.heatmap(pattern_mat, xticklabels=['A', 'B', 'C'], yticklabels=df_test_with_patterns.id.values)
ax.set(xlabel='Test Type', ylabel='# of individuals that took in a single day')
plt.show()
print
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on Erap answer, this works too, maybe slightly faster:

```
out = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index(['date', 'id'], drop=True).sort_index()).groupby(level=[0,1]).sum()
```

and then iterate through the different dates to get the different charts

```
for i in out.index.levels[0]:
    d = out.loc[i]
    plt.figure()
    plt.title(f'test for date {i}')
    sns.heatmap(d.gt(0))
```